# Installing pdf2image and pdf2json on mac

Tags: installation, flexpaper

I'm am having trouble making the source and install the 2 programs on mac lion.
Any clues on the errors show, or alternative conversion tools that I can use?
I'm using http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/default.jsp to publish the pdfs.

pdf2image:

```
~/Downloads/pdf2image-0.51 Tue Jan 03 12:36:04>make
cd goo; make
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
cd fofi; make
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
cd splash; make
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
cd xpdf; make
g++ -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local -I/Users/Tagent1/freetype.win32/include/ -I/opt/local/lib/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I./../goo -I./../fofi -I./../splash -I.            -o pdftops Annot.o Array.o BuiltinFont.o BuiltinFontTables.o Catalog.o CharCodeToUnicode.o CMap.o Decrypt.o Dict.o Error.o FontEncodingTables.o Function.o Gfx.o GfxFont.o GfxState.o GlobalParams.o JArithmeticDecoder.o JBIG2Stream.o JPXStream.o Lexer.o Link.o NameToCharCode.o Outline.o Object.o OutputDev.o Page.o Parser.o PDFDoc.o PDFDocEncoding.o PreScanOutputDev.o PSOutputDev.o PSTokenizer.o SecurityHandler.o SplashOutputDev.o Stream.o UnicodeMap.o XpdfPluginAPI.o XRef.o pdftops.o \
        -L../goo -lGoo -L../splash -lsplash -lfreetype -lGoo -L../fofi -lfofi -L../goo -lGoo -lm
ld: library not found for -lfreetype
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [pdftops] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

pdf2json:

```
~/Downloads/pdf2json-0.50-source Tue Jan 03 12:31:30>make
cd goo; make
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
cd fofi; make
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
cd splash; make
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
cd xpdf; make
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
cd src; make 
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Answer (score 1):

On my mac, `freetype2` is in

```
 /usr/local/
```

and not in

```
 /opt/local
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) to install pdf2image and pdf2json:

```
brew install pdf2image
brew install pdf2json
```

It handles all of the dependencies!